# Multiple Case where clauses

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I have a security table in SQL, 2 columns are of value and the columns can indicate any of the following information, multiple entries of the Option L or D might exist per user, the values in the value column, if either L or D will indicate the list of Warehouses the user have either access to or not, similar All would mean the user have access to all warehouses and None would be no warehouse access.

```
Option | Value
---------------
A      | All
N      | None
L      | xyz (Allowed value)
D      | xyz (Denied Value)
```

My problem are with the WHERE clause in SQL, i need to provision for all 4 scenarios and so far i am only able to provision for 3 of the 4 scenarios, looking at my last clause i need to switch between IN and NOT IN depending on the Option.

```
WHERE 
  (CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP(1) Value FROM [AllowDisallowNone] ('demo1', 'ARBranches')) = 'All' 
              THEN 'All'  END != Branch 
  OR
  CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP(1) Value FROM [AllowDisallowNone] ('demo1', 'ARBranches')) = 'None' 
              THEN 'None' END = Branch 
  OR 
  Branch IN  (SELECT  Value FROM [AllowDisallowNone] ('demo1', 'ARBranches')))
```

Are there any suggestions on how to do this more effecient?

Ok some more detail on the two tables:

Security table looks like this:

```
SELECT [Operator]
,[Type]
,[TypeOption]
,[Value]
FROM [_OperatorAccess]
WHERE [Type] = 'ARBranches'
```

Security table data:

[image: Security Table results]

Remember that similiar to `TypeOption = A` for the list of allowed branches, there might be users with the `TypeOption = D` for the list of denied branches.

I need to filter my Branch Table query to show only the branches the user has access to. If i split this up in 4 separate queries it would be something like this:

```
For TypeOption = A (All Records)
Select Invoice, Branch, InvDate FROM Branches  (No Where Clause necessary, because user have access to all Branches)

For TypeOption = N (No Records)
Select Invoice, Branch, InvDate FROM Branches WHERE Branch = '' (No Branches will be returned, becuase my Branch field cannot be null or empty.) 

For TypeOption = L (List of allowed branches)
Select Invoice, Branch, InvDate FROM Branches WHERE Branch IN (Select Value FROM _OperatorAccess WHERE Operator = 'RWOL' AND Type = 'ARBranches')

For TypeOption = D (List of denied branches)
Select Invoice, Branch, InvDate FROM Branches WHERE Branch NOT IN (Select Value FROM _OperatorAccess WHERE Operator = 'RWOL' AND Type = 'ARBranches')
```

I do hope this make's more sense.

Comment: could you post the complete query text including the SELECT block?

Comment: Could you please provide more details such as name, schema and sample data of the security table, code of the "AllowDisallowNone" function (it is a function, isn't it?) and cases of expected query results?

Answer (score 0):

Change your sub-queries to an `EXISTS` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM my_existing_query q
WHERE EXISTS (

    SELECT 1
    FROM [AllowDisallowNone] ('demo1', 'ARBranches')
    WHERE
    -- All warehouses permitted, or specific warehouse permitted
       (Value = 'All' AND Option = 'A')
    OR (Value = q.Branch AND Option = 'L')

    -- Deny permissions should override Allow permissions
    EXCEPT

    SELECT 1
    FROM [AllowDisallowNone] ('demo1', 'ARBranches')
    WHERE
    -- No warehouses permitted
       (Value = 'None' AND Option = 'N')
    OR (Value = q.Branch AND Option = 'D')
)
```